can opencv.js really find page corners
Does opencv.js findcontours really work (without needing constant refinements)?
Has anyone had any success with opencv.js in finding page corners? There is a lot of noise on various discussion sites about it's ability - but I cannot find it to work when looking for a document edge/corner and cannot find any definitive examples of any successful code
The code I'm playing with assumes a 4 point area and runs:

convert to grayscale
gaussianblur
adaptive threshold
gaussianblur
canny edge detection
find the largest area in any found contours

The js is:
let src = cv.imread(canvas);

// 1 Convert to grayscale
let dst  = new cv.Mat();
tracePos = 'cvtColor';
console.log(tracePos);
cv.cvtColor(src, src, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
debugImg(src, tracePos);


// 2 Apply Gaussian Blur to reduce noise
tracePos = 'GaussianBlur';
console.log(tracePos);
cv.GaussianBlur(src, src, new cv.Size(5, 5), 0);
debugImg(src, tracePos);


// 3 Apply adaptive thresholding
tracePos = 'adaptiveThreshold';
console.log(tracePos);
cv.adaptiveThreshold(src, dst, 255, cv.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv.THRESH_BINARY, 11, 2);
debugImg(dst, tracePos);


// 4 Apply Gaussian Blur to reduce noise
tracePos = 'GaussianBlur2';
console.log(tracePos);
cv.GaussianBlur(dst, dst, new cv.Size(5, 5), 0);
debugImg(dst, tracePos);


// 5 Apply Canny edge detection
tracePos = 'Canny';
console.log(tracePos);
cv.Canny(dst, dst, 100, 200, 3, false);
debugImg(dst, tracePos);


tracePos = 'findContours';
console.log(tracePos);
let contours  = new cv.MatVector();
let hierarchy = new cv.Mat();
cv.findContours(dst, contours, hierarchy, cv.RETR_EXTERNAL , cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);


let largestArea = 0;
let bestApprox  = null;

tracePos = 'loop';
for (let i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++) {
    let contour   = contours.get(i);
    let perimeter = cv.arcLength(contour, true);
    let approx    = new cv.Mat();
    cv.approxPolyDP(contour, approx, 0.02 * perimeter, true);

    doTraceRememberPoints(approx);
    if (approx.size().height === 4) { // If the contour is approximately a rectangle
        let area = cv.contourArea(approx);
            if (area > largestArea) {
            largestArea = area;
            bestApprox  = approx;
        }
    }
    else {
        approx.delete();  
    }
}


if (bestApprox) {
    drawContourPoints(bestApprox);
    bestApprox.delete(); // Release memory
    success = true;
}

src.delete();
dst.delete();
contours.delete();
hierarchy.delete();

The image I'm using is (one of many):

And the result of each debugImg() is


The 1st debug image is cvtColor
2nd is GaussianBlur
3rd is adaptiveThreshold
4th GaussianBlur2
5th Canny

It seems that the Canny is the least useful image - and the found area is nowhere near what is required...

What am I missing? Is opencv.js up to this - is there something that opencv.js (as opposed to the python opencv) is missing?

Don't convert to gray and use adaptive threshold or canny. Threshold on the input using cv2.inRange() on the brown-yellow pages. Then get the largest external contours. Then reduce vertices to 4 using cv2.approxPolyDP()

Thanks fmw42, but I'm not seeing this working. Also - the fact that this image has brown-yellow doesn't mean the next has too. :-(

I think canny is quite unnecessart here. If the background is always a white page, then filtering out the white and some morphological operations would be enough to extract the external contour of the page. cv2.threshold(gray,180,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY) followed by cv2.morphologyEx(final,cv2.MORPH_OPEN,cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT,(17,17))) actually gives a very good result.I write in python so thats all i can help.
